# How to end nodemon application that doesn't show in the terminal anymore?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I'm using express.js for a web application and I forgot to end the application when my computer went to sleep. Now if I close my terminal the application is still running on port 3000 but I don't want it to run anymore. It doesn't show anywhere that it's running so I can't end it anymore.

Is there a way to end all servers that are running?

I've tried to google my situation but none of the solutions worked for me.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: @yolenoyer I'm on windows 10

Comment: In the task manager, you should find a process running `node`. If there are several ones you must disambiguate them by looking at the parameters (`nodemon` should be visible). When you find the right process, kill it (I guess you can do it with right-click, but i don't use windows). I guess this can be done easily with power shell, in this case you should look how to search and manage processes with power shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to close the process node in the task manager and then re-running my application.

Answered by yolenoyer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process on port: 3000. You can **follow this step** to kill the process with port: 3000.

1. `Run CMD` as administrator.
2. Type Command: `netstat -aon`.
3. Now, you can see the port: 3000 and than look at the column PID. Get PID number from port: 3000.
4. After that, type command: `taskkill /f /pid [your pid]`. An example my PID from port: 3000 is 4545, Than i can type command: `taskkill /f /pid 4545`.
5. After that, you can get some message, "Proccess with PID has been terminate/stop".
6. End.

After you follow that's step above, than your server with port: 3000 has been killed.

I hope it's work.